# Beautifulsoup grabing the name but not the metascore of the webpages

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm geting the name I want but not the coresponding Metascore with this code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

# Define the URL
url = "http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/score/metascore/year/pc/filtered?sort=desc&year_selected=2018"

# not sure about this but it works (I was getting blocked by something and this the way I found around it)
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

web_byte = urlopen(req).read()

webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')

#this grabs the all the text from the page
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html5lib')

#this is for selecting all the games in from 1 to 100 (the list of them)
game_containers = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="product_item product_title")

# print(game_containers)

game_names = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="product_item product_title")
game_metascores_p = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="metascore_w small game positive")
game_metascores_m = html_soup.find_all("div", class_="metascore_w small game mixed")
game_user_s = html_soup.find_all("span", class_="data textscore textscore_favorable")

#lists to store the data
names = []
metascores = []
userscores = []

#Extract data from each game
for games in game_names:

    name = games.find()
    names.append(name.text.strip())

    metascore = games.find_next_sibling.()
    metascores.append(metascore.text.strip())
```

when I run the game name:

```
print(names)
```

I get the list of 100 names just the string (which is what I want)

when i run this :

```
print(metascores)
```

I get this:

```
['User:\n    7.6', 'User:\n    7.8', 'User:\n    7.0', 'User:\n    8.2', 'User:\n    7.3', 'User:\n    5.9', 'User:\n    7.2', 'User:\n    7.8', 'User:\n    8.1', 'User:\n    7.0', 'User:\n    8.5', 'User:\n    6.6', 'User:\n    7.2', 'User:\n    7.2', 'User:\n    7.3', 'User:\n    7.2', 'User:\n    7.5', 'User:\n    6.5', 'User:\n    7.5', 'User:\n    7.9', 'User:\n    7.8', 'User:\n    7.2', 'User:\n    7.6', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    7.9', 'User:\n    7.1', 'User:\n    6.1', 'User:\n    6.0', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    7.1', 'User:\n    6.6', 'User:\n    8.0', 'User:\n    7.7', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    7.5', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    8.1', 'User:\n    7.8', 'User:\n    7.7', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    7.9', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    5.4', 'User:\n    8.0', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    7.7', 'User:\n    8.0', 'User:\n    6.3', 'User:\n    8.0', 'User:\n    6.2', 'User:\n    8.3', 'User:\n    8.2', 'User:\n    8.3', 'User:\n    8.1', 'User:\n    5.1', 'User:\n    6.5', 'User:\n    7.5', 'User:\n    7.3', 'User:\n    6.7', 'User:\n    7.9', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    7.2', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    6.9', 'User:\n    5.4', 'User:\n    6.9', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    6.6', 'User:\n    7.9', 'User:\n    4.0', 'User:\n    6.8', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    6.1', 'User:\n    4.5', 'User:\n    6.2', 'User:\n    8.3', 'User:\n    4.5', 'User:\n    4.9', 'User:\n    7.7', 'User:\n    4.7', 'User:\n    7.9', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    6.9', 'User:\n    6.0', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    4.6', 'User:\n    7.3', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    7.5', 'User:\n    6.8', 'User:\n    6.4', 'User:\n    tbd', 'User:\n    4.1']
```

which is the user score (on the next variable which will be the user score, I would like to just get the number or tbd not including the "'User:\n'")

so how do I get the metascore and the user score (just the string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()`:

```
str.replace("User:\n    ", "")
```

like this:

```
metascoresNew = []
for i in metascores:
    temp = str(i)
    temp2 = temp.replace("User:\n    ", "")
    metascoresNew.append(temp2)
print(metascoresNew)
```

Output will be:

```
['7.6', '7.8', '7.0', '8.2'...]
```

***DEMO*** [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SJIImlmbX)

Comment: added example, please check

Comment: thanks that worked!!! now all i need is to get the metascore from the page do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

got the metascore to with this:

```
metascore = games.find_previous_sibling()
metascores.append(metascore.text.strip())
```